# Relation between Inserted and Deleted table's in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Let's say I have this table :

```
Car
----------------------
Name|Date|Color
```

The primary key is a combination of `Name` and `Date`.

On the update, if the initial `Color` of the updated row is Blue and the new one is Red, I want to keep a trace of this update.

This is what I did :

```
ALTER TRIGGER TraceTrigger
ON Car
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TraceTable
  SELECT
    del.Name,
    del.Date,
    del.Color,
    ins.Name,
    ins.Date,
    ins.Color
  FROM deleted as del
  INNER JOIN inserted as ins
  ON del.Name = ins.Name AND del.Date = ins.Date
  WHERE del.color = 'Blue' AND ins.Color = 'Red'
END
```

This example is pretty simple. It show that I need to keep a trace of X old value and X new value from the updated row.

But imagine if the `Name` can be modified (I know we should not modify PK, but in this situation, it is possible). Given that the primary key can change, sometimes, the relation between the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` table's will just not work.

So, it is possible to keep the relation between the deleted row and the inserted row when the PK can be updated to a different value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needn't bother recording both `INSERTED` and `DELETED`. Just `INSERTED` is what I usually do, otherwise you'd end up with 2 of every bit of information. You'll record it when its inserted, then you'll record the identical data when its deleted.

Say you've got a table that just has an `ID` and a `Name` field, the trace for that recording both `INSERTED` and `DELETED` would look like:

```
OldID  OldName    NewID   NewName
1      Harry      1       Henry
1      Henry      1       James
1      James      1       Thomas
```

As you can see, you're doubling up data. The left 2 columns are identical to the right columns except shifted up a row.

In terms of the primary key, if you know you might have to change the PK whilst wanting to maintain a history, I'd strongly recommend adding a surrogate key to the table (e.g ID) that you NEVER change, that way you are free to alter the name column as you wish.

Comment: Both tables are needed. If you find a record with the same key in both, it simply means that the record was updated, and there should be a difference in data somewhere. So, essentially, deleted contains data before the update, and inserted - after. This way, you can even compare if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You never really change a primary key; logically, you actually create a new entity (record / row ).  It is, in effect, a completely new thing.

There are a number of ways to keep track of this change, but here are two:

- Create a row identifier like an IDENTITY column.  It's not really a surrogate key, because a surrogate key should always be 1-1 with the proper natural key. Use this if name + date is not really the primary key and you can't create one (yuck - you have a database design issue).
- Update the data in your trace table to match the new value anytime a value in the PK changes.  This is the proper solution if your database design is correct.  You may be able to implement this with an ON UPDATE CASCADE foreign key constraint.